# Jquery date picker with button image in angular does not work with tab

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, tabindex

I have created a directive in angular to use jquery date picker which opens datepicker on  Click of a button using showOn: button. So it contains a input field and a button beside it. Its working fine.
 But how can we make the button to be clicked and date picker to open on press of tab from the input field in which date is filled after selecting date from datepicker.

Comment: If you tab from the input, the button gets focus. User will have to then click the button to activate the date picker. What you're asking for is against the common UX. Tabbing into a button won't normally trigger it's functionality... Did you mean pressing enter after focusing the input/button?

Comment: No the button is not getting focused even on pressing tab from the input corresponding to it. It directly is going to next input instead of button of date picker.

Comment: that's strange. Did you try adding a `tabindex` property? BTW I still think expected UX will be to display calender upon pressing `ENTER`. Tab is for moving around, not triggering functionality...

Comment: Yes I tried with tabindex it was not working. I know that tab can't do click event. But wanted to know if there would be any solution.